# Why can't I access webmin since installing Dansguardian and squid?

Tags: squid, webmin

I installed Webmin and it was working great until I installed DansGuardian & squid and then webmin stopped, if I try to log into webmin this is what am getting on Firefox.

> The proxy server is refusing connections  Firefox is configured to
>      use a proxy server that is refusing connections

Comment: Please keep in mind that webmin *may* damage your system, it is not compatible with the debian/ubuntu way of handling software and settings. See [Webmin on help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WebMin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox proxy configuration, enter the following in the "*No proxy for:*" text box:

```
localhost, 127.0.0.0/8, 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16
```